# How to stop an endless server thread by escape key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, jobs, terminate

I am trying to write a webSocket server in c#.
The server runs as a job:

```
using Unity.Jobs;
using UnityEngine;

public class ServerStartup : MonoBehaviour
{
    WebSocketServerJob server = new WebSocketServerJob();
    JobHandle jobHandle;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Starting up the websocket server...");

        jobHandle = server.Schedule();
        
        Debug.Log("...the server should be running in it's own thread now :-)");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Debug.Log("Escape key detected...stopping server!");
            server.StopSwitch = true;
            Debug.Log("Waiting for server tread to complete!");
            jobHandle.Complete();
            Debug.Log("Server tread complete...quitting app!");
            Application.Quit();
        }
    }


}
```

The server job is currently an endless job, but I would like it to end when I press Escape. However, just cancelling it from outside (using Abort or some such) will not be good as I first want to close the sockets and clean up. So the thread should get some kind of notice from outside that it is to terminate.

```
        //
// csc wsserver.cs
// wsserver.exe

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Unity.Jobs;
using UnityEngine;


public struct WebSocketServerJob : IJob
{
    bool stopSwitch;

    public bool StopSwitch
    {
        set { stopSwitch = value; }
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        StopSwitch = false;
        string ip = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 80;
        var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);

        server.Start();
        Debug.Log("Server has started on " + ip + ":" + port + " Waiting for a connection...");

        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        Debug.Log("ServerMsg: A client connected.");

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        // enter to an infinite cycle to be able to handle every change in stream
        while (!stopSwitch)
        {
            while (!stream.DataAvailable) ;
            while (client.Available < 3) ; // match against "get"

            byte[] bytes = new byte[client.Available];
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, client.Available);
            string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

            if (Regex.IsMatch(s, "^GET", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                Debug.Log("=====Handshaking from client=====\n" + s);

                // 1. Obtain the value of the "Sec-WebSocket-Key" request header without any leading or trailing whitespace
                // 2. Concatenate it with "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" (a special GUID specified by RFC 6455)
                // 3. Compute SHA-1 and Base64 hash of the new value
                // 4. Write the hash back as the value of "Sec-WebSocket-Accept" response header in an HTTP response
                string swk = Regex.Match(s, "Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Groups[1].Value.Trim();
                string swka = swk + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
                byte[] swkaSha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(swka));
                string swkaSha1Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(swkaSha1);

                // HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker
                byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                    "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" +
                    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
                    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" +
                    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + swkaSha1Base64 + "\r\n\r\n");

                stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                bool fin = (bytes[0] & 0b10000000) != 0,
                    mask = (bytes[1] & 0b10000000) != 0; // must be true, "All messages from the client to the server have this bit set"

                int opcode = bytes[0] & 0b00001111, // expecting 1 - text message
                    msglen = bytes[1] - 128, // & 0111 1111
                    offset = 2;

                if (msglen == 126)
                {
                    // was ToUInt16(bytes, offset) but the result is incorrect
                    msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { bytes[3], bytes[2] }, 0);
                    offset = 4;
                }
                else if (msglen == 127)
                {
                    Debug.Log("TODO: msglen == 127, needs qword to store msglen");
                    // i don't really know the byte order, please edit this
                    // msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt64(new byte[] { bytes[5], bytes[4], bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[9], bytes[8], bytes[7], bytes[6] }, 0);
                    // offset = 10;
                }

                if (msglen == 0)
                    Debug.Log("msglen == 0");
                else if (mask)
                {
                    byte[] decoded = new byte[msglen];
                    byte[] masks = new byte[4] { bytes[offset], bytes[offset + 1], bytes[offset + 2], bytes[offset + 3] };
                    offset += 4;

                    for (int i = 0; i < msglen; ++i)
                        decoded[i] = (byte)(bytes[offset + i] ^ masks[i % 4]);

                    string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);
                    Debug.Log(text);
                }
                else
                    Debug.Log("mask bit not set");

                //Debug.Log();
                //StopSwitch = false;
            }
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("server thread interrupted by main thread.");
        stream.Close();
        Debug.Log("stream closed...");
        client.Close();
        Debug.Log("TcpClient closed...");
        
        
                
    }
}
```

I thought about using an external static variable "stop" from the calling routine and set that to "true"
and replace the WHILE clause with something like "while(!stop)", but the documentation warns against that so what is the solution?

Looking at the sample in Microsoft's doc about Thread.Interrupt.Method I saw how they communicated with the thread using a public variable and changed the code to use that..."server.stopSwitch".
Looking at the cpu usage that seems to stop the thread, but the Unity editor gets stuck as well... so I have to terminate the task from the task manager :-/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you link to the documentation please?

Comment: You can use a interrupt. It's very similar to a "abort", but can can write an handler in your component. Just catch the `ThreadInterruptedException` and clear your sockets in the `catch`-block.

Comment: @Absinthe: "Can you link to the documentation please?" I don't know what "documentation" you are referring to?

Comment: @akop: I will check that out .. thx :-)

Comment: Your post mentions "but the documentation warns against that so what is the solution?"

Comment: Could you add your implementation for `WebSocketServerJob` ?

Comment: @Absinthe: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystemTroubleshooting.html

Comment: @derHugo:ok, here is the complete code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Interlocked` class to read and write thread save from an `long` variable.

So somewhere define the variable `long isRunning`.

Then at the start or before your schedule the server, you just the `isRunning` to 0

```cs
...
isRunning = 0;
...
jobHandle = server.Schedule();
...
```

The server can the read from this variable to check if it should run

```
while (Interlocked.Read(ref isRunning) == 0) { .. }
```

To communicate that the server should stop use `Interlocked.Increment`

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref isRunning);
```

The server will then stop working after the current loop-iteration is finished.

Comment: I eliminated all code in the loop but a Debug.Log and used the Interlock.Read which worked fine to stop the thread as predicted. Unity still has a problem with the application.quit that does not work and I will have to investigate what of the listener code makes things get stuck. But the Interlock clearly works to stop the thread. Many thx to you and all that gave me feedback :-))

Comment: see here for ending play mode in Unity:https://answers.unity.com/questions/899037/a.html

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the `CancellationTokenSource` class and can give the server some arguments.
Then do

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

var token = cts.Token;

// somehow give the token to the server

jobHandle = server.Schedule();
```

then can the server check wether or not he should stop, like

```
while (!token.IsCancellationRequested) { ... }
```

to stop the server do

```
cts.Cancel();
```

Comment: Unity does not like the cts it seems, bevause it is a reference type: InvalidOperationException: ```WebSocketServerJob.stopSwitch.m_source is not a value type. Job structs may not contain any reference types.
Unity.Jobs.LowLevel.Unsafe.JobsUtility.CreateJobReflectionData (System.Type type, Unity.Jobs.LowLevel.Unsafe.JobType jobType, System.Object managedJobFunction0, System.Object managedJobFunction1, System.Object managedJobFunction2) (at <d1422b3fc93746018c92eda852993b93>:0)...```

Comment: And I really like that cts construct...thx for pointing that out to me...will be using it when possible!

Comment: @Rachmaninow but the `CancellationToken` is a value type, might want to share your attemt of using the token? Maybe as a new question and link it here.